# Sync Framework, to group or not to group?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I realized that you can add a scope for the whole database or just a number of tables.

The question would be, if you're going to synchronize a full database, which would be preferrable, one scopename for the whole database, or would it be better to scope and synchronize per schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would depend on some factors: number of tables, frequency of update, sync direction, etc...

have a look at this: [SYNC FRAMEWORK SCOPE AND SQL AZURE DATA SYNC DATASET CONSIDERATIONS](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/sync-framework-scope-and-sql-azure-data-sync-dataset-considerations/)